# Boolean value didn't change despite input from text field

Tags: java, boolean

When I enter a number within a range in the text field, the boolean should change based on the number typed in. But it still remain false for the one between 10 to 30 and above 30. What am I missing in my code?

```
      Submitbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          { 
            int value = Integer.valueOf(candynumf.getText());
               if(value > 0 && value <= 10)
               {
                  candypackage1 = true;
                  candypackage2 = false;
                  candypackage3 = false;

               }
               else if(value > 10 && value <= 30)
               {
                  candypackage1 = false;
                  candypackage2 = true;
                  candypackage3 = false;
               }

               else if(value > 30)
               {
                  candypackage1 = false;
                  candypackage2=false;
                  candypackage3 = true;
               }   

               String candypack = String.valueOf(candypackage1);
               candypackage1bl.setText(candypack);
               });
```

Comment: Change ```candymuf.getText()``` to ```candymuf.getText().toString()```

Comment: I get an error for that though. oh numf means number field

Comment: Also, it is recommended to use ```Integer.parseInt()``` to get primitve value

Comment: Still false though

Comment: What value are you trying?

Comment: @Vishal Assuming `#getText()` returns a `String` (which is probably a safe assumption, though a [mre] would have made this clear), calling `#toString()` on the result is redundant.

Comment: I am trying to get the number from textfield and place in the if-else loop according to user input value. The values in if-else loop which is boolean will change based on user input. But the value I enter in numberfield didn't change the boolean condition.

Comment: Well there isn't any bugs for one thing... and it keep giving me false in the the last statement above from label at the end. Do I need to use another way to get the value instead from the text field? Although I not sure which way to do it like a range scale

Comment: In each of your `if` blocks, you are declaring *brand new variables* named candypackage1, candypackage2, and candypackage3.  You are assigning values to these new variables and not the candypackage1 etc. fields of your class.  Try removing the word `boolean` from each line in each `if` block.

Comment: well I just tested it again and it didn't really jump to second condition. I guess it's still buggy ==

Comment: any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Its okay, I think I figure out. Shouldnt use boolean at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is setting the local variable candypackage1 to true, not the field. You then set the text to the field candypackage1. Either move your code for setting text inside the if statement, move the local declaration outside the if statement, or set the field instead of creating a local variable.